# unix less - problem with Enter key on numeric keypad

Tags: unix, less

When I use the unix command 'less' I am constantly frustrated that using the Enter key on the numeric keypad doesn't work but instead types 'ESCOM'.

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 6):

This is because the number pad's Enter key sends a different command then the keyboard Enter key. You could globally re-map the key to send the normal Return/Enter command, but understand that it will effect how the key works in all the other programs too.

Here are some tips on how to [remap the key in X-Windows using *xmodmap*](http://dev-loki.blogspot.com/2006/04/mapping-unsupported-keys-with-xmodmap.html), or [in the console/terminal using *loadkeys*](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/187). You probably want to map keycode 104 ("KP_Enter") to the "Return" command.

Comment: The articles contain too much unrelated information. A simple excerpt would  be great!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`lesskey`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lesskey&sektion=1).

```
~ $ vi .lesskey
#command
\OM        forw-line
~ $ lesskey
```

If this character doesn't match the one in your keyboard try using the escaped octal value.
You can also use another action like `invalid` (beeps) or `noaction`.

Comment: I am still lost. How do I find out the octal value? How can I make this change permanent? What does `\OM` mean? What does `forw-line` mean? Why the comment at the top, has it any relevance?

Comment: The commands above should be enough, provided you know `lesskey` or read the linked `man` page.